# Namespacing versions of an PostgreSQL schema for backward-compatibility?

Tags: postgresql, namespaces, schema, version, backwards-compatibility

Say we have an SQL database with a table `Person` and several applications accessing it. For some reason we would like to modify the `Person` table in a backward-incompatible way.

One potential solution for keeping compatibility is to rename the table to `User` and to create a `Person` view that provides the same interface as the legacy table. (Add *on insert*, *on update* and *on delete* triggers as needed).

The approach has the problem that we might run out of available semantically correct names after a few changes.

Is there a well-known best practice for "namespacing" the schema "interface" according to the DB version?

Alternatively, is there a better way to maintain backward-compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a well-known best practice for "namespacing" the schema "interface" according to the DB version?

It's not a common requirement, but when I've seen the need for similar things I've tended to create a new schema that contains the backwards-compatible wrapper for the table in a separate schema (namespace). I then set the `search_path` on a per-user basis so that the user who needs the backward compat table sees it, and the others see the new version.

The BC view has a `RULE` or (in newer PostgreSQL versions) a `DO INSTEAD` trigger referring to the *current* version of the table explicitly from its normal schema, eg `public.People`, to support writes if required.

This only works if you need BC on a per-login-user basis where you can `ALTER USER ... SET search_path`, or (less likely) where you can set the application that needs BC to run a `SET search_path` command on each session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A friend of mine just gave me [an example](http://pastebin.com/UmbTABVp) of the solution you are proposing.